# why the scroll is appearing though there is no height nor a lot of information

Tags: html, css

The problem happens in this area

[image]

it goes down and I don't know why.

that area is this:

```
<div id="dl-menu" class = "dl-menuwrapper">
```

there is no height

and as you see, it just contains three `li`

1- why is that scroll appears?

2- how to remove it please?

#### Update 1

Code

```
.dl-menuwrapper {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #b1aea6;
    background: #fffcf5;
    min-height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 200%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 200%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have `min-height: 800px`. If you remove the [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height), the height will shrink to the size of the content.

Comment: I don't have min-height, I have min-width. OMG maybe by mistake i typed that

Comment: yes you right. thanks +1 I will accept it when the system allows

Comment: could you remove the jsfiddle please? thanks for your understanding

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I removed the fiddle, however, without any code this question becomes useless to others in the future. You may want to edit your question and add the relevant code that was in the fiddle.

Comment: you right, I just updated the question and added the relevant code

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually quite simple, if I'm correct.

Take a look at your css file, for the .dl-menuwrapper class.
You have a nasty little declaration there, which is this:

```
    min-height: 800px;
```

Comment: +1 thanks you very much but the other guy answered first and I must accept his answer, I wish I could accept more than one ansewr.

Comment: haha thank you ;] I don't mind - just remember to accept the best anwser.